# Notepad++ XML - Delete Tags Conditionally Based on Child Tag Content not containing certain content

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace, xml

I've got a large xml file where i need to remove some child elements if they do not contain the right start of a the content of a nested child element.

My xml file looks like this:

```
<product>
    <catalogEntry>
      <idPath><![CDATA[K212/G425638/G425649/G426239/G426265/G601769]]></idPath>
      <namePath><![CDATA[Web Katalog DK/Solar Plus/Solar Plus EL/Afsnit 12 - Kommunikations- & sikringsmateriel/Racks/Vægracks]]></namePath>
      <ImagePath><![CDATA[K212-{\pics\_catalogmanager\sz2\ikon_solarplus.jpg}{\pics\_catmandk_kampagner\sz2\ikon solar plus_el.jpg}{\pics\_catmandk_solar plus\sz2\solarplusel_afs.13.jpg}{\pics\cubic cabinet\sz2\5709832021591p.jpg}{\pics\mass creation\sz2\0000101760-6he2060020med20plade20a.jpg}]]></ImagePath>
    </catalogEntry>
    <catalogEntry>
      <idPath><![CDATA[K352/G600248/G600247]]></idPath>
      <namePath><![CDATA[Solar plus mini guide/Rack og tilbehør/Vægrack]]></namePath>
      <ImagePath><![CDATA[K352-{}{}]]></ImagePath>
    </catalogEntry>
    <catalogEntry>
      <idPath><![CDATA[K212/G425642/G444580/G444590/G444598]]></idPath>
      <namePath><![CDATA[Web Katalog DK/Kommunikation/Rack, tilbehør, kabel management/Vægrack/Solar Plus Vægrack]]></namePath>
      <ImagePath><![CDATA[K212-{\pics\_catalogmanager\sz2\ikon_kommunikation.jpg}{\pics\_catalogmanager\sz2\kommunikation_rack-skabe_.jpg}{\pics\lk dataconnect\sz2\5703302138918p.jpg}{\pics\mass creation\sz2\0000101760-6he2060020med20plade20a.jpg}]]></ImagePath>
    </catalogEntry>
    <catalogEntry>
      <idPath><![CDATA[K193/G389888/G395066/G585958/G586999/G600567]]></idPath>
      <namePath><![CDATA[PRODUCTS NOT VISIBLE IN WEB KATALOG DK/Grp7 - Kabel § Føringsveje § Data/157R - Rune Agersnap/Kampagnemails/Afsluttede kampagner/Nye Solar plus vægrack - Gældende til op med d. 05.05.19]]></namePath>
      <ImagePath><![CDATA[K193-{}{}{}{}{\pics\mass creation\sz2\0000101760-10he2050020med20plade20fri.jpg}]]></ImagePath>
    </catalogEntry>
    <catalogEntry>
      <idPath><![CDATA[K212/G425639/G426577/G426699/G426927/G426940/G600572]]></idPath>
      <namePath><![CDATA[Web Katalog DK/EL/(10.00 - 29.99) Stærkstrømsmateriel/12.00 Kapslings- og tavlemateriel/12.30 Rack-skabe inkl. tilbehør/Vægrack/Solar plus vægracks]]></namePath>
      <ImagePath><![CDATA[K212-{\pics\_catalogmanager\sz2\ikon_el.jpg}{\pics\_catalogmanager\sz2\10.00_29.99.jpg}{\pics\_catalogmanager\sz2\12.00.jpg}{\pics\cubic cabinet\sz2\5709832045535p.jpg}{\pics\cubic cabinet\sz2\5709832045399p.jpg}{\pics\mass creation\sz2\0000101760-6he2060020med20plade20a.jpg}]]></ImagePath>
    </catalogEntry>
```

I only need to keep the elements where the  element contains `<![CDATA[K212`
the other `<catelogEntry>` elements I need to delete

i've tried with some variations on this statement in find and replace
`<catalogEntry>(?:(?!</catalogEntry>.)+[^K212](?:(?!<catalogEntry>).)+</catalogEntry>\R`

but I get an non valid expression.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<(catalogEntry)>(?:(?!\1)(?!\[K212).)+</\1>\R?`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<(catalogEntry)>        # open tag and capture tag name in group 1
                # Tempered Greedy Token
(?:                     # non capture group
  (?!\1)                  # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't catalogEntry after
  (?!\[K212)              # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't [K212 after
  .                       # any character
)+                      # end group, must appear 1 or more times
</\1>                   # close tag
\R?                     # optional linebreak
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, i was just what i was looking for.

Comment: @CarstenKrogh-Simonsen: You're welcome, glad it helps.